# Import cordova project from git to visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I tried to import an existing Cordova project into visual studio 2015 with no success.

I only managed to clone the git, there is no .sln file and VS2015 doesn't know what to do with the repo.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What was the existing project created with a previous version of VS? If not, probably best to create a new cordova project in VS2015 and then add files manually from the existing project folder.

Comment: No it wasn't, I hoped VS could identify the project and wrap it with all the solution metadata files. I had no choice but to copy all the files to a new cordova solution. Thanks.